Cannot move UdpSocket to another thread, which is causing UI rendering issues
I am trying to move the networking task to another thread because its blocking the main thread.
Trying different classes and methods but cannot properly move it."
I think its still running in main causing UI rendering issues
#include "udphandler.h"
#include "custom/data/DataFile.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <QTimer>

UdpSocketHandler::UdpSocketHandler(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::ReceiveBufferSizeSocketOption, 20 * 1024); //20kb
    udpSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);

    connect(udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &UdpSocketHandler::onReadyRead, Qt::DirectConnection);

}

UdpSocketHandler::~UdpSocketHandler() {
    if (udpSocket) {
        udpSocket->close();
        delete udpSocket;
    }
}

void UdpSocketHandler::close() {
    udpSocket->close();
}


void UdpSocketHandler::bindSocket(const QHostAddress &m_address, quint16 m_port)
{
    if (udpSocket && udpSocket->bind(m_address, m_port, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint)) {
        qWarning() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Socket bound to Addr: " << m_address.toString() << " PORT: " << m_port;
    } else {
        qWarning() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Failed to bind UDP socket. Addr: " << m_address.toString() << " PORT: " << m_port;
    }
}


void UdpSocketHandler::onReadyRead()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());

        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());

        aerx::readDataFromStruct(datagram);
    }
}

#include "netorkthread.h"



NetworkThread::NetworkThread(const QHostAddress &address, quint16 port, QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
    , m_address(address)
    , m_port(port)
{
    setObjectName(QString("Network Thread"));
}

NetworkThread::~NetworkThread()
{
    requestInterruption();
    quit();
    wait();
}

void NetworkThread::init()
{
    qWarning() << "UDP Handler initialized in thread. " << QThread::objectName()
               << "\nAdd: " << m_address << ", Port: " << m_port;
    udpHandler = new UdpSocketHandler(nullptr);
    udpHandler->moveToThread(this);
    udpHandler->bindSocket(m_address, m_port);
}

void NetworkThread::deInit()
{
    if (udpHandler) {
        udpHandler->close();
        udpHandler->deleteLater();
    }
}

void NetworkThread::run() {
    init();
    exec();
    deInit();
}


// in main.cpp
NetworkThread networkThread(QHostAddress(offsetSenderIP), offsetSenderPORT);
networkThread.start();
QObject::connect(&app, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, [&]() {
  networkThread.requestInterruption();
  networkThread.quit();
  networkThread.wait();
});


The UI is better than directly creating udpHandler in main.cpp but still slowly whole application starts getting unresponsive.

Can we have complete (if abriged) main() code?  It looks weird what you had done here, Where QApp is exec()-uted if you had done that in main? QApplication or QCoreApplication message pump should come live first. A call to QThread::currentThread() -it's a static- allow you to get id of thread cotext to tell you if your assumption is wrong or not.

The main thread issues are probably due to fact it had made conenction before creating thread's message pump. At least THAT event would be run in hosting thread (main thread) context. It's only after QThread::exec() the QObject::connect is valid for created thread if it was automatic or direct connection.

main.cpp is around 700 lines
Can you please tell me what did i do wrong. Note that i am receiving 2kb of data every 11ms and problem is here while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {} running every 0ms, almost always executing and overusing CPU.

pfft, one of my projects at works have 320 microseconds beat (~330 times faster than yours?) and it's fine. You probably right and it runs in same thread as GUI. abriged version shouldn't contain anything program sepcific, you simply can prowide framework that does nothing,it just shuld be compilable and show order of createion and eventconnection and firing. It's odd that main() is that big, lots of initialization routines? Itlooks like you try to initialze and create QObject::connect too early.

Btw udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()  can be spurius on some platforms,so you have to check returned value of udpSocket->readDatagram. Among other things, there might be a rerror or  someonthing had sent a null-datagram, your input buffer may stay unaltered and you re-process same data twice.

Maybe That's not an issue, I think somehow it's bombarding with readyRead signal and that's interfering with main thread

Should not, unless you're on some exotic platform or you bombard Ui with some secondary event. if socket is in thread , the event is in that thread and not in main thread loop. How UI and network interact? The problem here is that you added a bunch of irrelevant to multithreading  code and only few lines that relevant

Would you like to write some codes?

Thanks a lot guys for your kind responses.
The problem was an old piece of code, where QML Repeater was used to create 55K rectangles and one value(from UDPSocket) was changing all Rectangle positions everytime data was recieved.
I fixed it by replacing the repeater with ListView and everything is fine.
@fridayPie
Thanks again.

Well, if you were scaling up event processing to these numbers - that's architectural problem which couldn't be seen wihtout seeing entirety of code. Your onReadyRead just was making things worse by not giving up processing time. There is simply a concept of having "not enough time" well known in real-time applications but overlooked in education to write something user-space.
